# Handlebars helper regular expression to mark select boxes in a multiple select input box

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars helper for choosing a select boxes state depending on what the user previously choose. It worked great when it only had to mark regular check box, however when trying to get multiple values to become checked in a multiple select input box and reading from an array in the Mongo database it breaks. It will select one box, but not multiple. Here's my code:

```
select: function(selected, options){
let selLength;
if(Array.isArray(selected)){
  selLength = selected.length
  let i;
  for(i = 0; i < selLength; i++){
    return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp(' value="' + selected[i] + '"'), '$& selected="selected"').replace(new RegExp('>' + selected[i] + '</option>'), ' selected="selected"$&');
  }
} else {
return options.fn(this).replace(new RegExp(' value="' + selected + '"'), '$& selected="selected"').replace(new RegExp('>' + selected + '</option>'), ' selected="selected"$&');
}
},
```